# Copy some files to projectDir when someone compile their project using my DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm not sure if this question has been asked or not.
I have created a DLL in C#. My DLL depends on other DLLs. When someone compile their project using my DLL, the other DLLs will get copy to the projectDir.

However, the other DLLs depend on some text files and some other executable files. The problem is that the text files and executable files don't get copy to the projectDir. Unfortunate, that will cause the project to crash when running.

My question is, how can I load those text files and executable files to the projectDir whenever my DLLs is compiled?

Thanks.

Comment: This is why you can write a post-build event.  Project + Properties, Build Events tab.  You'd generally use xcopy.exe with the /d option so it only copies when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are sharing it you could also look at using Nuget to publish out your DLL.  With Nuget you are able to specify and bring across dependent files and libraries that will be added to your any project just by including them as content in the DLL project.